# Bootstrap: Progress bar and receiving data from the user

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

this is going to be very basic question. What I'm trying to do is to have simple progress bar and a way to receive number from the user. Then I want my code to start when user clicks the button and display the data on the bar.

My js code:

```
var moveBar = function() {
var addPoints = prompt("Select amount:"); // Prompt and ask user for input
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");
bars[0].style.width = '"' + parseInt(addPoints) + "%"  + '"' ;
//console.log('"' + parseInt(addPoints) + "%"  + '"'); // Added for testing. Displays correct value, but code doesn't work.
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div id="prog" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    60%
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="progbar" value="Test" onclick="moveBar()"></input>
```

The code works fine as long as I use predefined value like here

```
bars[0].style.width = "50%";
```

What needs to be changed in order for it to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding quotes to the width which is wrong.
You should add the value without the quotes.

> Note that you are changing the width of the div. In order to see the
>   current progress you could add some background color to the div with id **prog**.

```
var moveBar = function() {
    var addPoints = prompt("Select amount:");
    // Prompt and ask user for input
    var bars = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar");
    bars[0].style.width = parseInt(addPoints) + "%";
    //console.log(parseInt(addPoints) + "%"); // Added for testing. Displays correct value, but code doesn't work.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you ! I still don't understand why quotes break the code in my particular example, but they are fine in this one:
bars[0].style.width = "50%";

Comment: Its ok because you are hardcoding it (you entered it manually and it is considered as string).